# Pyspark 3.2.0 - Mlib Pipeline - after using load() function Transform() returning empty dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

1. Using Windows10 and Hadoop 2.7.
2. Able to get predictions using transform() with Python 3.6 & 3.7 using Apache Spark 2.4.4 and 2.4.7.
3. After upgrading to Python 3.8.5 and Apache spark 3.2.0:
   Tried saved pipeline model,
   Model load and
   Used transform function to get prediction. ** retuning empty dataframe.

Able to load saved pipeline model, checked stages in pipeline object.

```
model.write().overwrite().save(saveDir)
tm = PipelineModel.load(saveDir_model)
spark_tdf = spark.createDataFrame(testData)
predDF = tm.transform(spark_tdf)
```

Comment: Are `saveDir` and `saveDir_model` the same?

Comment: yes, both are same @VladSiv